# How can I handle \n(new line character) in the code below

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int lines;
void m_cmnt(FILE *fp) 
{
    int prev = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) 
    {
        if (prev == '*' && ch == '/') 
        {
            return;
        } 
        else 
        {
            prev = ch;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "error in line %d: unterminated comment\n", lines+1);
}

int main ( int c , char **arr )
{
    FILE *fp , *np ;
    int ch , prev ;
    lines = 0;
    bool String=0 ;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r") ;
    np = fopen("temp.txt" , "w") ;

    if (fp==NULL )
    {
        printf ("Invalid/No Filename given as Argument ! \n") ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    while ((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF )
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;

        /* file pointer currently not inside a string */
        if ( !String )
        {
            if ( ch=='/' )
            {
                prev=ch ;
                ch= getc(fp) ;
                switch(ch)
                {
                    case '*'  : /*if(ch != 'a')
                                    putc('h', np);*/
                                m_cmnt( fp) ;
                                putc(' ', np);
                                 break ;
                    default   :
                                 putc(prev , np) ;
                                 putc(ch , np) ;
                                 break ;
                }
            }
            else putc( ch ,np ) ;
        }
        else  putc(ch , np) ;

        if ( ch=='\"' || ch=='\'')
            String = !String ;
        prev = ch ;

    }

    fclose(fp) ;
    lines++;
    printf("line = %d", lines);
    fclose(np) ;
    //remove(arr[1]) ;
    //rename( "temp.txt" , arr[1] ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

My friend and I are working on a self challenge project and the above code is a program that removes comment from the "test.txt" file and writes the non comment part to temp.txt file. It only works for multi comment(intentional).

I was trying to handle \n character to make new line when it occurs inside a comment and outside a comment. For example `line1\nline2` should be exported in different lines. Also `line1/*comm\nent*/line2` should be exported(written) in different lines as well. But if the escape character occurs in string or character literal it should be treated as a normal string or character.

Comment: You will have to keep track of when you are in a string/character literal. What you are then doing is "lexical analysis", a pretty advanced topic.

Comment: To expand on my comment, your `bool String` is not sufficient, since it will fail when a `""` double quoted string containes `'` single quotes, and vice versa. You also probably want to handle escapes quotes: `'\''`.

Comment: To give you a tip to avoid massive switch statements and if/elseif chains: add a function `bool expect(int c) { int d = fgetc(fp); if (d == c) return true; fungetc(d, fp); return false; };`. With this function you also don't need to do any of the bookkeeping you are currently doing with `prev`, `ch`, etc.

Comment: How do I even start? Do I use a second loop to check for \n or can I just use if statement in the main function. I am new to programming so I need better than an idea.

Comment: Although I have written many lexers in the past, I am not going to give an entire lecture about lexical analysis. I have come across many pitfalls regarding lexing, but the `expect` function handles most of them, and in general makes the code much easier to read and reason about IMHO. I wrote some pseudo-C code that should show you how you can approach basic lexical analysis, you can copy it or study it to find out how you can improve your own lexers.

Comment: `if ( ch=='\"' || ch=='\'')
            String = !String ;` is insufficient. It assume a `"` or `'` toggles being in/out of strings (and character constants).  Consider `"\""`, `"\'"`, `'\"'`,  `'\''`.

Comment: In general, you have at least 5 states: normal, in `""` string, in `''` constant, in `/* */` comment, in `// eol` comment.

Answer (score 1):

> a program that removes comment(s)

Code needs a new approach to robustly handle case like `"\""`, `"\'"`, `'\"'`, `'\''`, `// '`, `/* " */`, `"//"` etc.

In general, you have at least 5 states: Normal, in `""` string, in `''` constant, in `/* */` comment, in `// eol` comment.

Suggested re-reworked algorithm.

```
// Pseudo code
while ((c=get()) != EOF) {
  if (c == ''') process_quote();  
  else if (c == '"') process_double_quote();
  else if (c == '/') {
    next = fgetc() 
    switch (next) {
      case '*': process_slash_star_comment();
      case '/': process_slash_slash_comment();
      default: unget(next); put('/');
  else put(c)
}
```

All bets are off is code does something like `#define x //`.

Comment: Why isn't the outer one also a switch? Also, line-continuation is a concern for process_slash_comment().

Comment: @Deduplicator True, code could use an outer `switch` .  The `if else` seemed more clear.  True also about " line-continuation is a concern for process_slash_comment()" and that would be handled inside that sub-function - not returning until `*/` or `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want (untested/unchecked)

```c
// TODO: includes

FILE *fp;

bool expect(int c) {
  int d = fgetc(fp);
  if (d == c) return true;
  fungetc(d, fp);
  return false;
}

// handle things differently while inside a string/char literal.
void quoted(int q) {
  while (true) {
    if (expect(q)) break; // found matching quote, leave the function
    // skip over character escape sequences
    // FIXME: does not handle multi-character escape sequences correctly
    if (expect('\\')) putchar('\\');
    putchar(fgetc(fp)); // NOTE: will also print character after '\\'
  }
}

// In response to the comment
bool escnl(void) {
  if (expect('\\')) {
    if (expect('n')) {
      putchar('\n'); // found \n!
      return true;
    }
    fungetc('\\', fp); // found backslash but not a \n
  }
  return false;
}

int main(void) {
  // TODO: initialization

  while (true) {
    if (expect('/')) {
      if (expect('*') { // found a comment!
        while (true) { // search for the end
          // if (expect('\n')) putchar('\n'); // emit newlines in comments, as requested // commented out as per answer comment
          if (expect('*') && expect('/')) break; // found the end!
          if (!escnl()) fgetc(fp);
        }
      }
      else putchar('/'); // found a slash, but wasn't a comment
    }
    else if (expect('\"')) quoted('\"');
    else if (expect('\'')) quoted('\'');
    else if (expect(EOF)) break;
    else if (!escnl()) putchar(fgetc(fp));
  }

  // TODO: cleanup

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the pseudo-code but I didn't say to emit \n character I said to handle it to provide new line.

Comment: @Brook So you want a slash followed by "n" to turn into a newline? I will update the answer.

Comment: Corner: Use of `quoted(q)` is OK here, yet fails to perform as desired in general usage when `q<0` as `d == c` will not match in `expect()` - `fgetc()` gets `unsigned char` values.

Comment: @chux True, updated. You should generally use `int` instead of `char` for reasons like this. To correct you, though, `fgetc` returns an `int`, not `unsigned char`, and returns `-1` or some other negative value in case of EOF.

Comment: I did not say `fgetc()` returns an `unsigned char` but values of `unsigned char`.  Perhaps more clear: It return `int` values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.

Comment: @chux Also not necessarily true, `char` may be signed as well. In fact, signed integer types are theoretically faster, since signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, among other things. I find it rarely matters, but I have seen horror stories with 2x+ performance when using signed types.I have worked with compilers that define char to be signed. It makes sense on embedded systems where you only care about ASCII. But in a world of UTF-8 char is usually unsigned.

Comment: @ YoYoYonnY yes that is exactly what i want. \ followed by "n" to turn into newline. but not if it is inside string or character literals.

Comment: @Brook Then re-examine my answer, I have added an `escnl` function that searches for that sequence, and outputs a newline character when it finds it.

Comment: @ YoYoYonnY what is fungetc in your code? I don't think it is defined anywhere.

Comment: Whoops, that's supposed to be [ungetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ungetc/), there is no `fungetc` because `ungetc` already takes a `FILE *`

Comment: It is true.  `fgets()` returns values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  It makes no difference to `fgets()` if `char` is signed or unsigned (unless on rare platforms where `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`).